# MySQLi Select list dependent on the selected previous

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have a database with 2 tables and a page with 2 select lists.
According to the value selected on the first select, I want to show the corresponding items on the second select.

There are no errors or anything, but the second select does never show anything, so I'm probably missing something.
Can someone help me?

Connection.php

```
    <?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dberror1 = "Could not connect to the database";
$dberror2 = "Could not find the table";

$Conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ($dberror1);

$Select_db = mysqli_select_db($Conn, 'swimming') or die ($dberror2);

?>
```

Results.php

```
    <?php
include ("Connections/connection.php");

$query_comp = mysqli_query($Conn, "Select * FROM comp");

?>

<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Swimming Results</title>
<link href="file:///D|/Websites/Swimming/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Div for Title -->
    <div id="title">    
        <p>Swimming Results</p>
    </div>


<form name="results"    > 

    <!-- Div to Choose competition -->
    <div id="competition">
        <p>Competition</p>


      <select name="sel_comp">
        <option value="">---Select one competition---</option>

    <?php

    while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_comp)){
        echo "<option value='{".$fetch['id']."}'>".$fetch['comp_name']."</option>";

}


?>
</select>





  </div>


    <!-- Div to Chose event -->
    <div id="event">
        <p>Event</p>



        <select name="sel_even">
        <option value="">---Select one event---</option>

    <?php
    $chosen=$_POST["sel_comp"] ;
    $query_even = mysqli_query($Conn, "Select comp.id, events.cid, events.event_name FROM events, comp WHERE events.cid = $chosen");


    while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_even)){
        echo "<option value='{".$fetch['event_id']."}'>".$fetch['event_name']."</option>";

}
?>
</select>

    </div>

    <!-- Div to Show results -->
    <div id="results">
        <p>Resultados</p>
    </div>

    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code is interpreted server-side, before displaying to the user's browser. So this code can't know anything about the choices the user will do.

If you want a "dynamic sub-select", you need to add some javascript code. That javascript code will run on the user's browser and will be able to react to the user's action on the first select box.

Comment: Ok... And what it is the simplest way of doing that?
Is my code on the right path or do I need to change a lot?

Comment: Your code is a great beginning :) I do not have enough time to give complete help, sorry. What you need is 1/ understand how to build a data structure in javascript from PHP containing all infos needed to link the first and second select options, then 2/ add js code that will, from the choice inthe first select, populate hte second select. That's not totally trivial, but is a very interesting exercise as it's a current use case in web dev.

Comment: I started including script and it's storing and everything, but when trying to load something into the div is not working. I'm trying simple, without even passing arguments yet, and just showing some text on that div, and not working. Is there something wrong with the code on this line?     $("#event").load("get_event.php");

Comment: That code seems correct, but maybe you put this js code to the wrong place. Don't know. You should probably open a second "question" on stackoverflow with this new problem, to get better help.